# Abrir enlaces externos de una WebView en el navegador predeterminado

Tags: android, webview

Desarrollé una *WebView* en Android Studio que muestra una página web de ventas, pero el inconveniente es que las páginas que contienen enlaces hacia otros sitios web externos continúan abriéndose en la misma actividad y no en el navegador predeterminado del usuario, como debería suceder, ya que los mismos no pertenecen a la web...

Les dejo el código preliminar que tengo en **MainActivity**:

```
package com.predetermined.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "show";
    private ProgressBar spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("https://web.com");

    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        WebView miVisorWeb;
        miVisorWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (miVisorWeb.canGoBack()) {
                        miVisorWeb.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            if (ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse.equals("show")) {
                webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "hide";
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    }
}
```

Como pueden ver, está aún en el horno... Y allí está el código que muestra la web, la pantalla de bienvenida y demás.

Si saben de alguna solución al respecto, se agradece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso además de sobreescribir `onPageStarted()` y `onPageFinished()` agrega `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, aquí es donde abrirías los enlaces en el navegador usando un intent:

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        //Abre url en browser.
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString())))
        return true;
    }
```